# What is the better way to handle multiple filters in react js(Creating the states for each filter or creating and Object for all filters)?

Tags: reactjs

In my application I have more than 20 filters. I am creating the state for each filter but when ever I want change the one filter based on the other filter change its calling the API multiple times.

Expecting a better solution for this type of issues.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
getCustomerList();
},[isChecked, isUpdated])


While loading the component its calling getCustomerList 2 times.